# how to use Loopback mongoDB with SSL certificate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I just trying to find out how to use SSL certs with the mongo Strongloop Loopback connector. Didn't find anywhere in the docs or googling

Answer (score -1):

In `datasource.json` section mongo db do like :

```
...
"url": "mongodb://localhost:27017/app_db?ssl=true",
"server": {
    "sslValidate": true,
    "sslCA": "path to file"
    },
...
```

Note that I have not tested this, but I think it would work.

Answer (score -2):

please use datasources.json as below

```
app_db: {
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 27017,
"database": "test",
"name": "app_db",
"username": "youruser",
"password": "yourpassword",
"connector": "mongodb",
"ssl":true,
"server": {
  "auto_reconnect": true,
  "reconnectTries": 100,
  "reconnectInterval": 1000,
  "sslValidate":false,
  "checkServerIdentity":false,
  "sslKey":fs.readFileSync('path to key'),
  "sslCert":fs.readFileSync('path to certificate'),
  "sslCA":fs.readFileSync('path to CA'),
  "sslPass":"yourpassphrase if any"

}
```

username,password,auto_reconnect, tries and interval all are optional
use this link to get the certificates using openssl
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/